# Using ESP32-CAM (with ov2640 camera image sensor) to send image via USB

Tags: arduino-ide, i2c, usb, esp32, web-server

I was trying to obtain image from ESP32-CAM (with ov2640 camera image sensor).

I obtained the image through camera web server by connecting the ESP32-CAM and PC to same wifi network. A USB to TTL module was used to interface ESP32-CAM to PC.

Program was uploaded to ESP32-CAM using arduino IDE

Reference video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5uvl6kDFJY

ESP32-CAM development board and ov2640 CMOS image sensor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fa2W.jpg

CP2102 USB to TTL module:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr0YV.jpg

Since this system involved wifi I had some serious trouble in obtaining the image:

- Entering wifi credentials
- Connecting the ESP32-CAM and PC to same wifi network
- with variations in wifi speed image display lags which is the main problem

So I was hoping to transfer the image from ESP32-CAM to PC via USB just like connecting a USB webcam to PC.

Can anyone please help to find a solution?

Comment: You would have to write some special software for your PC to receive the camera data over the USB UART connection - then send it over the USB UART connection from the ESP32 in the format that you have decided upon.  It can *never* be a webcam, since the CP2102 is a UART adaptor.

Comment: Why not just use a webcam?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I'am not using webcam since its form factor and cost is not reasonable. Do you have any suggestion regarding the special software that you mentioned?

Comment: Did you make it out eventually?